# Is this Overview of the Database Development Process Accurate

Tags: database-design

According to the Oracle Academy service, the process of Database Development has three steps:

1. Analyze
2. Design
3. Build

According to Oracle Academy, the process of Analyzing the data includes creating a conceptual data model using an Entity Relationship Diagram. The next step, design, involves translating that conceptual model into a table instance chart. Finally, build refers to the actual implementation of the database by creating the code needed to build the physical structure of the database.

Is this information accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accurate if you choose to follow that approach. I'm sure some people do still work that way, but in my opinion it's much too simplistic as a description of modern development methods. Perhaps Oracle Academy's focus is on teaching some basic skills rather than telling you how to run a project; or perhaps they have just been recycling the same old content for 30 years!

Database development doesn't usually work in isolation and not everything starts with a data model. Databases co-exist with other layers of a software stack and delivery normally requires collaboration between developers, analysts and designers across different technologies. Most software projects today are iterative to some degree so it isn't sufficient to view development as a single sequence with a definite start and end.